# How to make sure the $var variable in expanded in "$varsomething"?

Tags: bash, shell, variable-substitution

I'm trying to run something like this

```
for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
     do 
           run_this_command whatever.$nx$n.in
     done
```

The files are named as whatever.1x1.in, whatever.2x2.in, whatever.3x3.in, etc.

The code I copied below does not work. How do I make it so I can have "nxn" in the file name inside the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the loop, you want:

```
run_this_command "whatever.${n}x${n}.in"
```

so that the shell knows you're talking about $n, and not $nx.